# Who cooked and served food for the prisoners of Azkaban?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors, azkaban

As far as I remember, there were only inmates and Dementors mentioned as Azkaban inhabitants. Were there servants or house elves who cooked?

<sub>(The question is inspired by a silly comic strip with a dementor holding a tray).</sub>

Comment: Most likely the trays restock themselves by magic or something :P Never thought about this before, +1 , looking forward to actual answers.